# JSON how find another value at the same index from a value in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

A simple question I'm sure, but I can't figure it out.

I have some JSON returned from the server

```
    while ($Row = mysql_fetch_array($params))
    {
        $jsondata[]= array('adc'=>$Row["adc"], 
                           'adSNU'=>$Row["adSNU"],
                           'adname'=>$Row["adname"],
                           'adcl'=>$Row["adcl"],
                           'adt'=>$Row["adt"]);
    };

echo json_encode(array("Ships" => $jsondata));
```

...which I use on the client side in an ajax call. It should be noted that the JSON is parsed into a globally declared object so to be available later, and that I've assumed that you know that I formated the ajax call properly...

```
if (ajaxRequest.readyState==4 && ajaxRequest.status==200 || ajaxRequest.status==0)
        {
            WShipsObject = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText);

            var eeWShips = document.getElementById("eeWShipsContainer");

                for (i=0;i<WShipsObject.Ships.length;i++)
                {
                    newElement = WShipsObject.Ships;
                    newWShip = document.createElement("div");

                    newWShip.id = newElement[i].adSNU;
                    newWShip.class = newElement[i].adc;

                    eeWShips.appendChild(newWShip);


                } // end for

        }// If
```

You can see for example here that I've created HTML DIV elements inside a parent div with each new div having an id and a class. You will note also that I haven't used all the data returned in the object...

I use JQuery to handle the click on the object, and here is my problem, what I want to use is the id from the element to return another value, say for example `adt` value from the JSON at the same index. The trouble is that at the click event I no longer know the index because it is way after the element was created. ie I'm no longer in the `for`loop.

So how do I do this?

Here's what I tried, but I think I'm up the wrong tree... the `.inArray()` returns minus 1 in both test cases. Remember the object is globally available...

```
$(".wShip").click(function(){

    var test1 = $.inArray(this.id, newElement.test);
    var test2 = $.inArray(this.id, WShipsObject);

    //alert(test1+"\n"+test2+"\n"+this.id);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way of finding the index as asked, but I created a variation on the answer by Devraj.

In the solution I created a custom attribute called `key` into which I stored the index.

```
newWShip.key = i;
```

Later when I need the index back again I can use `this.key` inside the JQuery `.click()`method:

```
var key = this.key;
var adt = WShipsObject.Ships[key].adt;
```

You could argue that in fact I could store all the data into custom attributes, but I would argue that that would be unnecessary duplication of memory.

Answer (score 0):

For one you can simply use the ID attribute of the DIV to store a unique string, in your case it could be the index.

We do similar things in Google Closure / Javascript and if you wire up the event in the loop that you are creating the DIV in you can pass in a reference to the "current" object.

The later is the better / cleaner solution.

Comment: I have already used the `id` to store a unique key, but I don't want it to be the index because of nomenclature. I don't think attaching the JQuery in the loop will help because normally speaking you attach the Jquery handlers after the page has loaded fully - in the `.load()`method, and in this case there are other dynamically built elements that will depend. Of course I've stripped down the code to the necessary functionality for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".wShip").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).id;
  var result;

  WShipsObject.Ships.each(function(data) {
    if(data.adSNU == id) {
      result = data;
    }  
  });

  console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: This answer gets the id of the clicked object but I already know that from `this.id`. What I'm trying to do is use the `id` as the `key` to find `adt` as stored in `WShipsObject.Ships.adt` at the same index as the `id`

Comment: Are you sure? `($(this).attr('id'))` should use the id of the clicked object as the key of the object `WShipsObject.Ships`.

Comment: I must be missing something. How would I then use the result `data` proposed to obtain `WShipsObject.Ships.adt` at the correct index?

Comment: Sorry, I read your original data structure incorrectly. I've updated my answer appropriatly.

Comment: @devmatt This is similar to the `for` loop I used during the compilation of the page. I discounted this as being heavy handed (although agree it works). I was looking for a much more elegant solution. Something that would allow me to either find and use the index, or point directly to the data using another key. If I knew what the index was without looping I'd just be able to do `WShipsObject.Ships[index].adt`

Comment: What about including the index as a data attribute when creating the element?