# How to access an object's contents in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl

When I do

```
$.each(result, function(i, n){
alert("key: " + i + ", Value: " + n );
});
```

then for each iteration I see

```
key: 276, Value: {"owners":["he"],"users":["he","m"],"end":"07/06-2011","groups":[],"type":"in"}
```

How do I access the values of `owners`, `users`, `end`, `groups`, and `type` for each iteration?

In Perl would I have done

```
foreach my $key (keys %result) {
   print $result{$key}{owners};
   print $result{$key}{users};
   ...
}
```

**Update**

I get `result` from JSON like so

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/cgi-bin/ajax.pl",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "cwis" : id },
    // ...
    success: function(result){
    if (result.error) {
        alert('result.error: ' + result.error);
    } else {

        $.each(result, function(i, n){
        alert( "key: " + i + ", Value: " + n );

        });


    }
    }
});
```

**Update 2**

It seams that the problem is the server side is not sending prober JSON.

This is the server side script that generate the JSON string.

```
!/usr/bin/perl -T

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI qw(:standard);
use JSON;
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
$cgi->charset('UTF-8');

my $json_string = qq{{"error" : "The user do not have any activities."}};

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
$json = $json->utf8;

# @a and $act is now available

my $data;
foreach my $id (@a) {
    $data->{$id} = $json->encode(\%{$act->{$id}});
}
$json_string = to_json($data);


print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print $json_string;
```

Comment: can you also show the result that the perl script generates ?

Comment: I'm no CGI expert but it looks like you are double encoding your data into JSON. Once with `my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref; $json = $json->utf8;` and then again with `$data->{$id} = $json->encode(\%{$act->{$id}})` . Can't say I've ever tried to do that before!

Comment: @T9b : You are exactly right! That was the problem =) If you post is as a solution, then I accept it =) Thanks a lot =)

Comment: @ Sandra Schlichting - I'll update my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.write(result[key].owners);
document.write(result[key].users);
```

UPDATE:

Apparently my comment on the question was the answer:

> I'm no CGI expert but it looks like
>   you are double encoding your data into
>   JSON. Once with

```
my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref; $json = $json->utf8;
```

> and then again with
>
> $data->{$id} = $json->encode(\%{$act->{$id}}) .

Comment: are you by any chance trying to create JSON in the values? Are you sure it's been formated correctly, and then parsed correctly? Are you generating it manually or is it received from some feed?

Comment: `result` comes from JSON, so I am trying to access data that have been JSON decoded. In 1 minute will I have updated the question with the Ajax call.

Comment: Can you change it to `alert( "key: " + i + ", Type: " + (typeof n) );` and tell us the results? It certainly looks like the JSON is not being parsed properly somehow.

Comment: @Björn : It says it is string. In a minutes time will I post the servide side script.

Answer (score 2):

in `$.each` callbacks, `this` points to the current element, so

```
$.each(result, function(i, n){
     alert(this.users);
});
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined` when I try that.

Comment: @stereofrog : In my case the data looks different. Notice that everything in my Value is in closed in just one set of `{}`. The data comes from JSON, if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Sandra  I guess you're getting `undefined` on the first iteration when `n` is `integer`

Comment: @stereofrog : Basen on Teneff's answers it seams that my `result` isn't an object. I suppose that is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
n.owners or n['owners']
n.users or n['users']
etc.
```

In a loop...

```
$.each(result, function(k,v) {
    console.log("key: " + k + ", value: " + v );
    $.each(v, function(k,v)) {
        console.log("key: " + k + ", value: " + v );
    });
});
```

Comment: I also get `undefined` in both cases here.

Answer (score 1):

you can access them like this:

```
n.owners
```

or

```
n['owners']
```

or you can use another cycle :

```
$.each(result, function(i, n){
    if (typeof(n)=='object') {
        $.each(n, function(k, v){
            alert('n.'+k+' = ' + v);
        });
    }
});
```

**edit:**
[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KAVP9/)
[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/KAVP9/1/)

**edit2:** to avoid getting `undefined` make a simple check whether the key `i` is equal to `"Value"`, so it's value will be an object

Comment: okay, this is very interesting. I am getting `is not an object` when I use your code from jsFiddle on my data.

Comment: @Sandra just `"is ..."` ... no key name ?

Comment: When I use your code from example 2 on my data, it always enters your `else`-condition.

Comment: @Sandra try `alert(typeof(n));` and check what `n` actually is

Comment: @Teneff : It returns string. So I guess the problem is on the server side then?

Comment: @Teneff your answer works for the first field. It doesn't for the second and the third field returns undefined. After that all fields are errored @Sandra Schlichting - the reason I asked if you were using JSON is that I'm pretty sure it's not encoded properly. I'm not sure what your square brackets are supposed to achieve. Check the question I set here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194180/json-how-find-another-value-at-the-same-index-from-a-value-in-javascript-object

Comment: @Sandra if it's a `string` you could try `n=eval(n);`

Comment: @Teneff : When I try `n=eval(n); alert(n);` I get `invalid label` in the console.

Comment: @Teneff : Yes, it is temping to believe that the problem is in the server side script based on all this. I have posted the script, and am looking into right now